# VLC is not showing Cyrillic characters in the Windows titlebar

Tags: vlc-media-player, language, characters

VLC is not showing Cyrillic characters in the Windows titlebar. Instead, it shows some kind of code for each letter like &#1045.
Any way to fix it? I'm listening to some random Russian radio and the title is great for knowing the name of the song without just restoring the window.

Comment: It looks as though VLC does not handle this form of Unicode encoding, though you may like to experiment with [these settings](https://wiki.videolan.org/Change_Subtitles_Encoding/). Is there another player or browser which displays the Cyrillic characters correctly?

Comment: I have already tried those settings but don´t seem to work, maybe VLC do not consider the titlebar as subtitles, but is weird, i play a youtube video and the Cyrillic characters seems to appear correctly

Comment: I suspect that YouTube is using 16-bit encoding, while your radio station is using 8-bit (hence the escape sequence). What happens when you try to play the radio station in your browser?

Comment: It showes nothing in the title bar, just the tabs but no name or text, is an url that ends in .mp3